# Where to go to have code reviewed?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Several times I've finished a project, and always thought it would be helpful to have more experienced people look at my code. Quite obviously this does not fit the Stack Overflow Q&A format. What sites should be used for this, an is there one in the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: [codereview.se]

Comment: @Mysticial Code reviews on Code Review? Now that's just crazy talk.... :) (Handuel: make sure your code works though. Code Review is not a debugging service).

Comment: lol... the [first question on the homepage](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24239/what-is-the-voltage-in-china-do-i-need-to-bring-my-own-adaptor) of Code Review is completely off topic...

Comment: @Bart Yes, If I wanted debugging I'd ask about the algorithm I was having trouble with on stackexchange, this is for working complete projects when I want others opinions on how I've structured my project.

Comment: @Mysticial I just noticed that too, I think it's a travel company that is spamming.

Comment: @Mysticial spam it is. Flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is for you.

From it's [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for **sharing code from projects you
>   are working on** for peer review. If you are looking for feedback on a
>   specific working piece of code from your project in the following
>   areas…
>
> - Best practices and design pattern usage
> - Security issues
> - Performance
> - Correctness in unanticipated cases
>
> then you are in the right place!

But remember:

> if your question is not about a particular piece of code and instead
>   is a generally applicable question about …
>
> - Tools, best practices, improving, or conducting code reviews
> - Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets
> - Higher-level architecture and design of software systems
>
> then your question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted.